# Deleting a Cell from TableView and from Database

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, tableview

I'm building a Browser, and I have a database where the bookmarks of my browser are stored.

In my table "Bookmarks" I have an "ID (AUTOINCREMENT)" and a "URL" field.
The thing is, when I delete an arbitrary ID there remains a hole in my database. Like "ID1, ID2, ID700"...
and when I go and list this in a TableView, these are skipped.

So, row number 1, isn't necessary the ID number 1.

How can I manage to delete a row in my TableView, and delete the corresponding field (ID and URL) from my Database at the same time?

Here is a piece of my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//CRIA A CELULA DESTA LINHA DA TABELA
static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    //FAZ CACHE DA CELULA PARA EVITAR CRIAR MUITOS OBJETOS DESNECESSARIOS DURANTE O SCROLL
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//RECUPERA O NUMERO DA LINHA 0, 1, 2, 3...
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

self.counter = 1;

NSString * bookmark = [[Dados sharedDB]getBookmark:row+1];

//TEXT
if ([bookmark isEqualToString:@"ERROR"]) {

    do {
        self.counter++;
        bookmark = [[Dados sharedDB]getBookmark:row+self.counter];
    } while ([bookmark isEqualToString:@"ERROR"]);
}

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", bookmark];

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to first delete the data in database and then fetch the modified(new) data from database and reload the tableview.

So how it works is, you have to make use of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to know which row has been selected. Using `indexPath.row` property, determine the ID of that entry ( I believe you must have fetched all the data in an array before displaying). Then, in database, delete that particular entry. Assuming, you are using core data, you will have to fetch that entry, delete it and then save it in managed object context. After this is done, fetch all the data and store it in the array of your view controller. Last, call the method of `[self.tableview reloadData]`.